# Is American pronunciation "optional" for Americans?

Tags: phonetics

1. Stop consonants: b,p,g,t,d,k are pronounced very lightly or not at all, but this is optional.
2. For instance, "wait"/weit|/ or /weit/, "stop"/st^p|/ or /st^p/
3. Variations in t pronunciation: /d/, /t/, omitted, or not, they can all be true t.
4. For instance, "important/importnt/ or /impord^nt/ or /import^nt|/ or /import^nt/ are all okay

So if I were to speak like a British person in the US -- assuming, of course, that the British way is to pronounce the true sounds of all the letters enlisted above -- would that pass as sounding legitimate?

PS I know some of these words are poorly used -- like "true", "legitimate" and so forth, and some of the phonetic symbolism may be way off, but I expect that the message does come through.

Comment: As an American, I can generally understand British people, and would generally say they're speaking English. So in that sense yes, "proper British pronunciation" (RP) is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Where did you get those rules?

Answer (score 1):

If you speak British English (RP), Americans will say "Hmmm, he speaks British English. I wonder if he is from Britain". If you speak Geordie, you'll need to repeat yourself – but I'm not sure if you would call that "British English". Even Derry English is sort of comprehensible to Americans. But I think it isn't consonant pronunciation that contributes to difficulty in comprehension, it's the vowels.

I would be surprised if anyone who speaks American English could consciously suppress just the stop allophonic rules typical of American English, and instead follow the UK model (ˈwikʰɛnd). If you exclude linguists from the subject pool, I expect that AE speakers would not find such pronunciation to be completely foreign. If it was noticed at all, would probably be thought of as being one of myriad local dialects.